# blocking main thread on async/await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, dapper

I am trying to make my base repository class asynchronous and I am running into some trouble. I am using Dapper ORM in my C# application.

*Base method*

```
protected async Task<List<T>> Read<T>(CommandDefinition cmd) {
    using(SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(Config.DBConnection)) {
        await myCon.OpenAsync();

        IEnumerable<T> results = await myCon.QueryAsync<T>(cmd);

        List<T> retVal = results.ToList();

        myCon.Close();

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

*Calling method*

```
public List<Category> GetAllActiveCategories(Guid siteGuid) {
    return base.Read<Category>(SPNAME_GETALLACTIVE, siteGuid).Result;
}
```

Everything looks in order to me. I have the method declaration decorated with the async keyword. I am awaiting on asynchronous methods.

The problem that I am having is that the thread blocks on `await myCon.OpenAsync();`. This is my first attempt at using async and await, so I am sure that I am doing something wrong, but it is not obvious. Please help!

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy I think you are on to something. I'll edit most to show one of the methods I am using that is blocking it.

Comment: now that you've posted the consuming side, I'm confident. Reposting my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The posted Read code is fine. The issue is in the consuming code. It's common to get a deadlock with `async` if you call `Wait()` or `Result` on the returned `Task` or its antecedent `Task` up in the call chain.

As always in these cases, the general advice applies: [don't block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Once you start using `async/await`, you should be using `async/await` throughout your entire call chain.

So, your calling method becomes

```
public Task<List<Category>> GetAllActiveCategoriesAsync(Guid siteGuid) {
    return base.Read<Category>(SPNAME_GETALLACTIVE, siteGuid);
}
```

... or

```
public async Task<List<Category>> GetAllActiveCategoriesAsync(Guid siteGuid) {
    List<Category> result = await base.Read<Category>(SPNAME_GETALLACTIVE, siteGuid);

    // Do something.

    return result;
}
```

Comment: my only question becomes how do I access the results at the top most level without blocking it

Comment: @fizch, unfortunately, async has a way of "poisoning" your code - in that you have to rewrite the *entire* chain to be `async`. Of course, if you're working with a synchronous calling chain you can always use the old-school blocking methods in your particular case. Alternatively you can fix your problem by using `ConfigureAwait(false)` on all `Task`s awaited inside your `Read` method, but, while it is a best practice to do so, intentionally blocking on `Task`s is still an antipattern and should be avoided.

Comment: But I digress as I am no longer answering the original question as stated.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is:

```
return base.Read<Category>(SPNAME_GETALLACTIVE, siteGuid).Result;
```

As Kirill noted, any time you use `.Wait()` or `.Result` on a Task, you are blocking synchronously. What you need to do is this:

```
public Task<List<Category>> GetAllActiveCategories(Guid siteGuid) {
    return base.Read<Category>(SPNAME_GETALLACTIVE, siteGuid);
}
```

This will return a Task to the calling method of *this* method, and so on... it has to be async "all the way up".

If the top-level consumer of this code is ASP.NET, you're fine. Just return a `Task<IActionResult>` (or the appropriate return type wrapped in a Task) and the framework will sort out the `await`ing for you.

If you're writing a console application or otherwise can't make it "async all the way up", you'll have to either block on `.Result` or make your method `async void` and use `await`. Neither one is a great solution, sadly. Async/await is pretty aggressive in the sense that you really do have to use it throughout your stack.

Comment: @fizch Added a little explanation. Kirill's answer (and link) are also good info!